# react-native android MediaDocuments provider uri reading file error

Tags: android, image, react-native, permissions, provider

I'm using `react-native-document-picker` component, in a `react-native` application development, to let the user choose an image file. I get back an uri representing the file selected by the user. Then, when I try to get the image size through `Image.getSize()` component function, the following error shows on the console running `react-native log-android`:

```
Failed to get size for image: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:298
```

Digging a little bit deeper I run a console with `adb logcat` to find the following error:

```
E DatabaseUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:298 from pid=3785, uid=10075 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

I already have the following permissions in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />` does not make any difference.

**So, which is the proper way to use the uri to access the image file data?**

simplified code sample:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';
import { DocumentPicker, DocumentPickerUtil } from 'react-native-document-picker';

export default class ConsultationForm extends Component<{}> {
  _filePicker = () => {
    DocumentPicker.show({
      filetype: [DocumentPickerUtil.images()],
    }, (error,res) => {
      Image.getSize(decodeURIComponent(res.uri), (width, height) => {
        console.log({width: width, height: height});
      });
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._filePicker()} >
          <Text>file picker</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

- operating system: Linux Mint v18.3
- node: v9.2.0
- react-native-cli: 2.0.1
- react-native: 0.52.0
- api level: 21
- virtual avd device Nexus_5X_API_24

Comment: Any update about it?